# proof of Taylor's theorem proposition

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $(a, b)$ and $x_0 \in (a, b)$.

If there exists a constant $M > 0$ for which $|P_n(y)| ≤ M$ for all $y ∈ (a, b)$ and $n \in N$, then, for each $x \in (a, b)$, $f(x) = lim_{n \to \infty}P_{n,x_0}(x)$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for clarity.

Comment: And please state the definition of $P_n(x_0)$...... For formatting click on Help on the top bar, choose Help Center,  and under Our Model,click on How Can I Format Math's Here?, read that and click on the Quck Reference at the end of it, read that, and have a look at the Shorter List of special symbols.... BTW a bounded infinitely differentiable function can fail to be equal to its power series.